# I have received a badge for a question I have never seen before

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I just got [annoucer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer?userid=764846) badge for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25433/764846) question.

- I have never seen this question
- None of these tags are favourite nor known
- I don't even know such language exists (or whatever it is)

I didn't find my referal link (https://stackoverflow.com/q/25433/764846) anywhere on google, nor SE sites I visit.. Is that a bug?

Comment: You've never heard of [Lisp](http://xkcd.com/224/)?? :p

Comment: @Chris: Like a twice in my life

Comment: In all seriousness, though, it's possible that someone else mistyped their ID in a referral link...

Comment: @Chris: Oh. I didn't even consider this. Still, this links isn't in google nor I can find it via [internal search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F25433%2F*%22&submit=search)

Comment: As an aside: linking from within SE-sites [won't give you](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) the badge anyway.

Comment: I did it, as a test of your meta-reporting speed. ;P

Comment: @JeremyBanks: hi! Hah, it was slower than before. I was half-sleeping when I got it yesterday and now I reallized I forgot about that one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it wasn't you, I can't tell you who the donor was who gave you that present, but *someone* [submitted that question to Reddit with your user ID](http://www.reddit.com/r/reddit.com/comments/l3bzz/why_are_computers_such_unreliable_pieces_of_shit/). It didn't receive much attention there; otherwise you'd probably have received more than a bronze badge…

Comment: Can I ask how did you find it? I can't find it in [google](http://www.google.com/search?&q=http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F25433%2F764846)

Comment: @genesis-φ: I have access to a bit more data :) I checked the logs for refer(r)ers for requests going to that link.

Comment: If it had hit the front page with thousands of upvotes, if would still have been a bronze badge, really.

Comment: @lunboks: That's true. I can't get silver and bronze badges for single question