# Star in link(s) in comments is removed

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

My recent [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108725/164007) with text

```
@Chris: Oh. I didn't even consider this. Still, this links isn't in google nor I can find it via [internal search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F25433%2F*%22&submit=search)
```

Had to offer link to search `url:"http://stackoverflow.com/q/25433/*"`. However, that star was removed in url, so from (removed Stack Overflow url)

```
/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F25433%2F*%22&submit=search
```

I got

```
/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F25433%2F%22&submit=search
```

instead, without that start, it's also visible in source code

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F25433%2F%22&amp;submit=search">internal search</a>
```

Comment: You can also see the problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F25433%2F*%22&submit=search)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>An asterisk is not in the sanitizer's character whitelist for URLs, so it will be removed. You have to UrlEncode it as `%2a`.</s>

From the next build on, the star will not be removed, but encoded, and thus the link will work fine.

See [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88297/url-filter-goes-rogue-on-unicode-characters-in-urls/128824#128824) for details.

Comment: Any chance the search could encode that in its URL too?

Comment: @Arjan - that would be a reasonable work-around for: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108466/the-free-form-text-in-other-flag-broke-a-pasted-url too

Comment: Note that this actually works for Markdown URLs [in regular posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20936/a-star-in-a-url-breaks-the-linkification-in-posts/108507#108507) (where the `*` is encoded to become `%2a`), but not for Markdown URLs in comments. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: As for search: the URL in the location bar after submitting a search for `url:"http://stackoverflow.com/a/*"` does not encode the asterisk, but yields `q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fa%2F*%22`. Hence, it cannot be used in comments [like so](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fa%2F*%22), but only when manually encoding the asterisk first, [like so](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fa%2F%2A%22). It would be nice if the search encoded for us... :-)