# Asterisks break URLs

Tags: bug, questions, comments, hyperlinks

### Problem

1)

```
http://wayback.archive.org/web/20110615000000*/libgd.org/Documentation
```

When simply pasted in question or comments, this URL keeps just the first part linked ( http://wayback.archive.org/web/20110615000000*/libgd.org/Documentation )

2)

```
http://wayback.archive.org/web/20110615000000*/http://libgd.org/Documentation
```

When simply pasted, this URL

- in comments: breaks up in two ( second comment to this question )
- in question: keeps first part linked ( http://wayback.archive.org/web/20110615000000*/http://libgd.org/Documentation )

But * is a valid URL character ( [Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid) )

### Workarounds

There is a workaround to adding such URL in question - just use the toolbar button in the question context box.  "Go [here](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20110615000000*/libgd.org)"

In comments, the quick help box contains details on the syntax (it works).

### The bug

This enquiry relates to the feature of making hyperlinks automatically just when URLs are pasted.

Related:

- [A star in a URL breaks the linkification in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20936/a-star-in-a-url-breaks-the-linkification-in-posts) status-completed
- [Star in link(s) in comments is removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108726/star-in-links-in-comments-is-removed/) status-by-design "An asterisk is not in the sanitizer's character whitelist for URLs"

Comment: http://wayback.archive.org/web/20110615000000*/libgd.org/Documentation Test comment.

Comment: http://wayback.archive.org/web/20110615000000*/http://libgd.org/Documentation

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20936/a-star-in-a-url-breaks-the-linkification-in-posts allegedly fixed though - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108466/the-free-form-text-in-other-flag-broke-a-pasted-url is more annoying because you can't edit to fix once it's obvious it's broken.

Comment: Not a dupe. This one here is about **comments** which use a different markdown, and **it is not fixed**.

Comment: I just ran into a similar issue on [Retrocomputing](http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/336/621), but there are no asterisks in the archive.org URL.  Is it related at all?

Comment: Also realised this: https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*zRhzFUQ_bWSwe3oc2WM-TA.jpeg