# Popular Question not awarded when question was deleted right after 1k views

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, popular-question

I like collecting badges in pairs, when possible. I recently noticed that two of my questions  had view counts in the mid-900s, so I decided to go for a pair of Popular Questions. After [getting them some attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108725/i-have-received-a-badge-for-a-question-i-have-never-seen-before) they both passed 1,000. However, I only got one badge.

One of the questions, [Simple Lisp Program Causing Computer To Hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433/simple-lisp-program-causing-computer-to-hang), seems to have been deleted in the interval between passing 1,000 and the badge-awarding-script running. If the script had been scheduled slightly differently, I think the badge would have been awarded.

If the cause is just this coincidence of timing, rather than by-design, this seems like a bug.

Comment: Do views after deletion from 10k users count towards the question view count?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ: The view count has gone up since I posted this, so apparently they do. Maybe I was mistaken about what happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If the script had been scheduled slightly differently, I think the badge would have been awarded.

At which point you would have had an *extra* badge. And the next time one of your questions passed 1K views, you wouldn't have gotten a badge for it. This is by-design.

In other words, you got lucky. The timing issue saved you from the ignominy of an undeserved badge, and the crushing disappointment of achieving one only to find you already had it.

Comment: I forgot that the next badge wouldn't be awarded. [tag:by-design] it is.

Comment: I seem to remember they changed this so that the "extra" badge is still awarded, but I can't find the post that announced it.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like `by-design` to me.  Badges aren't awarded instantly.  There's a script that runs on a schedule to check and award them.  I don't see any reason why the script would check deleted questions to award badges to them.